# Cannot print bibliography despite changing backend to biber, print bibliography says empty bibliography

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

Hi I have tried a lot of things and gone through several questions posted earlier but I can't seem to get my bibliography to print. I get the following errors:

1. Empty Bibliography (when I write \printbibliography)
2. Undefined Control Sequence (when I overwrite file contents for reference.bib in my main.tex)

Things I have tried:

1. Changing the backend to biber and biblatex both. None worked.
2. Adding overwrite file contents and reinputting the bib file content in main.tex and then cite them one by one using \citep{}
3. Changing styles

I have posted all of my code here (main.tex) in case there are some other code lines that might be messing with the use package of bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=29.7cm,includehead,headheight=1.5cm,pdftex,hmargin={3cm,2.5cm},vmargin={0cm,2cm},]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{sectsty}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, hhline}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\lstset{
    mathescape=true,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily
}
%\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\references.bib}
@article{chandrakasan1995minimizing,
  title={Minimizing power consumption in digital CMOS circuits},
  author={Chandrakasan, Anantha P and Brodersen, Robert W},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={83},
  number={4},
  pages={498--523},
  year={1995},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

 @misc{ enwiki:1062224546,
    author = "{Wikipedia contributors}",
    title = "CMOS --- {Wikipedia}{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
    year = "2021",
    howpublished = "\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CMOS&oldid=1062224546}",
    note = "[Online; accessed 30-December-2021]"
  }
  
  @article{Bankman2018AnA3,
  title={An always-on 3.8$\mu$J/86\% CIFAR-10 mixed-signal binary CNN processor with all memory on chip in 28nm CMOS},
  author={Daniel Bankman and Lita Yang and Bert Moons and Marian Verhelst and Boris Murmann},
  journal={2018 IEEE International Solid - State Circuits Conference - (ISSCC)},
  year={2018},
  pages={222-224}
}

@book{ann, title = {Artificial Neural Networks}, author={Ajith Abraham}, journal={Oklahoma State University, Stillwater, OK, USA}}

@article{courbariaux2016binarized,
  title={Binarized neural networks: Training deep neural networks with weights and activations constrained to+ 1 or-1},
  author={Courbariaux, Matthieu and Hubara, Itay and Soudry, Daniel and El-Yaniv, Ran and Bengio, Yoshua},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1602.02830},
  year={2016}
}

@ARTICLE{104196,
  author={Boser, B.E. and Sackinger, E. and Bromley, J. and Le Cun, Y. and Jackel, L.D.},
  journal={IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits}, 
  title={An analog neural network processor with programmable topology}, 
  year={1991},
  volume={26},
  number={12},
  pages={2017-2025},
  doi={10.1109/4.104196}}
 
 @article{article,
author = {Li, Ji and Yuan, Zihao and Li, Zhe and Ding, Caiwen and Ren, Ao and Qiu, Qinru and Draper, Jeffrey and Wang, Yetang},
year = {2017},
month = {03},
pages = {},
title = {Hardware-Driven Nonlinear Activation for Stochastic Computing Based Deep Convolutional Neural Networks}
}

@article{forssell2014hardware,
  title={Hardware implementation of artificial neural networks},
  author={Forssell, Mats},
  journal={Information Flow in Networks},
  volume={18},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2014}
}

@article{davari1995cmos,
  title={CMOS scaling for high performance and low power-the next ten years},
  author={Davari, Bijan and Dennard, Robert H and Shahidi, Ghavam G},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={83},
  number={4},
  pages={595--606},
  year={1995},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
 
@article{ng1996performance,
  title={Performance of CMOS differential circuits},
  author={Ng, Pius and Balsara, Poras T and Steiss, Don},
  journal={IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits},
  volume={31},
  number={6},
  pages={841--846},
  year={1996},
  publisher={IEEE}
}



\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\linespread{1.6}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Interim Report - 20203108}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page {\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\l@chapter}{\bfseries\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{2}{2em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{3}{2em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{4}{2em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{subsection}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}

\input{Section/0.Title}
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Section/1.Introduction & Project Aim}

\chapter{Project Background}
\input{Section/2.Project Background}

\chapter{Literature Review}
\input{Section/3.Literature Review}

\chapter{Outline of Approach \& Preliminary Results}
\input{Section/4.Outline of Approach}


\chapter{Ethics \& Sustainability}
\input{Section/5.Ethics & Sustainability}

\chapter{Project Work Plan}
\input{Section/6.Project Work Plan}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\citep{chandrakasan1995minimizing}
\citep{enwiki:1062224546}
\citep{Bankman2018AnA3}
\citep{courbariaux2016binarized}
\citep{104196}
\citep{article}
\citep{ann}
\citep{davari1995cmos}
\citep{forssell2014hardware}
\citep{ng1996performance}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

- `\citep` is a natbib macro. If you want to use it in biblatex, you must use the `natbib` option when you load biblatex.
- you shouldn't load package more then once. You MUSTN'T load them more than once with different options. An error message will explicitly tell you about the option clash for the geometry package
- the syntax `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\references.bib}` is wrong, `references.bib` should just be the filename, not a (non-existent) macro
- the `note` field in the wikipedia entry caused come probelems, so I moved it to another field.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=29.7cm,includehead,headheight=1.5cm,pdftex,hmargin={3cm,2.5cm},vmargin={0cm,2cm},]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{sectsty}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, hhline}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\lstset{
    mathescape=true,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily
}
%\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{chandrakasan1995minimizing,
  title={Minimizing power consumption in digital CMOS circuits},
  author={Chandrakasan, Anantha P and Brodersen, Robert W},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={83},
  number={4},
  pages={498--523},
  year={1995},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@misc{enwiki1062224546,
  author = "{Wikipedia contributors}",
  title = "CMOS --- {Wikipedia}{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
  year = "2021",
  howpublished = "\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CMOS&oldid=1062224546} [Online; accessed 30-December-2021]"
  }
  
@article{Bankman2018AnA3,
  title={An always-on 3.8$\mu$J/86\% CIFAR-10 mixed-signal binary CNN processor with all memory on chip in 28nm CMOS},
  author={Daniel Bankman and Lita Yang and Bert Moons and Marian Verhelst and Boris Murmann},
  journal={2018 IEEE International Solid - State Circuits Conference - (ISSCC)},
  year={2018},
  pages={222-224}
}

@book{ann, title = {Artificial Neural Networks}, author={Ajith Abraham}, journal={Oklahoma State University, Stillwater, OK, USA}}

@article{courbariaux2016binarized,
  title={Binarized neural networks: Training deep neural networks with weights and activations constrained to+ 1 or-1},
  author={Courbariaux, Matthieu and Hubara, Itay and Soudry, Daniel and El-Yaniv, Ran and Bengio, Yoshua},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1602.02830},
  year={2016}
}

@ARTICLE{104196,
  author={Boser, B.E. and Sackinger, E. and Bromley, J. and Le Cun, Y. and Jackel, L.D.},
  journal={IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits}, 
  title={An analog neural network processor with programmable topology}, 
  year={1991},
  volume={26},
  number={12},
  pages={2017-2025},
  doi={10.1109/4.104196}}
 
 @article{article,
author = {Li, Ji and Yuan, Zihao and Li, Zhe and Ding, Caiwen and Ren, Ao and Qiu, Qinru and Draper, Jeffrey and Wang, Yetang},
year = {2017},
month = {03},
pages = {},
title = {Hardware-Driven Nonlinear Activation for Stochastic Computing Based Deep Convolutional Neural Networks}
}

@article{forssell2014hardware,
  title={Hardware implementation of artificial neural networks},
  author={Forssell, Mats},
  journal={Information Flow in Networks},
  volume={18},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2014}
}

@article{davari1995cmos,
  title={CMOS scaling for high performance and low power-the next ten years},
  author={Davari, Bijan and Dennard, Robert H and Shahidi, Ghavam G},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={83},
  number={4},
  pages={595--606},
  year={1995},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
 
@article{ng1996performance,
  title={Performance of CMOS differential circuits},
  author={Ng, Pius and Balsara, Poras T and Steiss, Don},
  journal={IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits},
  volume={31},
  number={6},
  pages={841--846},
  year={1996},
  publisher={IEEE}
}



\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\citep{chandrakasan1995minimizing}
\citep{enwiki1062224546}
\citep{Bankman2018AnA3}
\citep{courbariaux2016binarized}
\citep{104196}
\citep{article}
\citep{ann}
\citep{davari1995cmos}
\citep{forssell2014hardware}
\citep{ng1996performance}


\end{document}
```

[image]